# Query to order by post pattern like 9gag

Tags: sql

Random thought when I was browsing 9gag:

They order their post in the following pattern (3pic followed by 1 gif):

- pic
- pic
- pic
- gif
- pic
- pic
- pic
- gif

So I thought, Their table structure might look something like this:

```
Posts
ID | Title | ContentUrl | Type | UploadedDateTime
1       AAA        abc.a    Pic     4/10/17 11:54
2       AAB        abc.b    Gif     4/10/17 11:55
3       AAC        abc.c    Pic     4/10/17 11:56
4       AAD        abc.d    Pic     4/10/17 11:57
5       AAE        abc.e    Gif     4/10/17 11:58
6       AAF        abc.f    Pic     4/10/17 11:59
7       AAG        abc.g    Pic     4/10/17 12:00
```

Can I write an sql query that returns me such order without using a cursor?

Edit:I can't believe the amount of people who don't know 9gag.

Basically they'll make sure that they will show exactly 3 pictures between showing a gif in the hot page. So the order in this case will look like:

```
5       AAE        abc.e    Gif     4/10/17 11:58
7       AAG        abc.g    Pic     4/10/17 12:00
6       AAF        abc.f    Pic     4/10/17 11:59
4       AAD        abc.d    Pic     4/10/17 11:57
2       AAB        abc.b    Gif     4/10/17 11:55
1       AAA        abc.a    Pic     4/10/17 11:54
3       AAC        abc.c    Pic     4/10/17 11:56
```

Comment: and why is that a problem?

Comment: Which 3 Pic and which 1 gif? Is there any order? Any logic?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn it's a problem because I don't know if I can write an sql query statement for this without any programming.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't really have a specific dbms, I just want to know if there's a way to do this even if it's vendor specific.

Comment: @GurV I am not sure, but my best guess will be:
1) ensure every 2 gif be separated by 3 pic
2) order by datetime
3) in case if there's not enough entries to fulfill condition 1 then prune the dataset until it can but I guess that's too complicated.

Comment: The answer will probably depend on the dbms used.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server solution:

```
With Posts (ID, Title, ContentUrl, [Type], UploadedDateTime) As (
    Select   1, 'AAA',    'abc.a',  'Pic', '4/10/17 11:54' Union All
    Select   2, 'AAB',    'abc.b',  'Gif', '4/10/17 11:55' Union All
    Select   3, 'AAC',    'abc.c',  'Pic', '4/10/17 11:56' Union All
    Select   4, 'AAD',    'abc.d',  'Pic', '4/10/17 11:57' Union All
    Select   5, 'AAE',    'abc.e',  'Gif', '4/10/17 11:58' Union All
    Select   6, 'AAF',    'abc.f',  'Pic', '4/10/17 11:59' Union All
    Select   7, 'AAG',    'abc.g',  'Pic', '4/10/17 12:00'
) Select *,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By [Type] ORDER BY Title) - 1)
    * (CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Gif' THEN 3 ELSE 1 END) As _Ordinal
 From Posts
 Order By _Ordinal, [Type]
```

---

```
ID  Title   ContentUrl  Type    UploadedDateTime    _Ordinal
2   AAB     abc.b       Gif        4/10/17 11:55           0
1   AAA     abc.a       Pic        4/10/17 11:54           0
3   AAC     abc.c       Pic        4/10/17 11:56           1
4   AAD     abc.d       Pic        4/10/17 11:57           2
5   AAE     abc.e       Gif        4/10/17 11:58           3
6   AAF     abc.f       Pic        4/10/17 11:59           3
7   AAG     abc.g       Pic        4/10/17 12:00           4
```

Row number Gifs and Pics separately multiplying Gif Ordinals by 3.

P.S. Nice ad for your resource. :-)